# Mapping an attribute in nvarchar to another column with int data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this as legacy and it seems impossible to solve it in T-SQL ... (?).

I need to map one column of table A to another column of Table B, THIS mapping is done using a parametrization table. All 3 tables are in the same server, in the same application. The staging table is an intermediate table to receive external data, and then it will feed the final table clean, after the mapping.

Table_a (staging table)

```
ID    NAME   rack     object
-----------------------------
1     x       y       zz:zz1   
2     x       y       zz:zz2
```

table_b (clean table - BEFORE the mapping)

```
ID  Name    rack   object
--------------------------
230  x        y    null
245  x        y    null
```

I want to achieve the next table_b after mapping.

Table_b (clean table - final table after mapping)

```
ID  Name     rack   object
---------------------------
230  x        y        10
245  x        y        11
```

How to relate both tables if the Ids are different for the same Name/Rack. for example, table A has id 1 for name/Rack as x and y. The same case for the table B is under id 230.

table_parametrization

```
Id   nameObject
---------------
10   zz:zz1
11   zz:zz2
```

The column `object` in `table_a` is of `nvarchar` type, and column `object` in `table_b` is of `int` type.

I do not even know how to achieve it in T-SQL.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. [This](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is probably the best place to get an idea.

Comment: What is the logic for relating `Table_a ID 1` to `table_b ID 230`?  You say "The same case for the table B is under id 230." but how do you know that?

Comment: And where do the magical values of 10 and 11 come from?

Comment: @SeanLange they come from `table_parametrization`, based on joining to the Staging table on the `Object`

Comment: well, the table staging is fed by Excel data. And then later, after some transformations, it will feed the table clean, but unfortunately the data type is not the same in the column object. There is no logic that we can relate those ids , id1 to id230... hence this is impossible.. I suppose.

Comment: Correct, if there is no way to link ID 1 to ID 230 anywhere, then what you want is impossible.

Comment: 10 came from the parametrization table... it means zz:zz1. It was translated. Column object in table clean is an INT data type, hence, it should receive the 10 coming from the parametrization table.

Comment: Without some table definition this is just too vague for me. I get it is in another table but some kind of detail is required.

Comment: Tab, yes, I think it is impossible to do the update using T-SQL.

Comment: This question is very unclear to me. The tables lack a relationship to join on. Also, it seems the OP want to join the rows by row order, but that doesn't work in a SQL database, as it would in Excel (or example).

Comment: Where does the data in `table_b` come from? Does it matter which ID (230,245) gets mapped to which object in `table_a`? Is `table-b` sorted, or does it otherwise have another column that can be used to differentiate between the two similar records?

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some wild assumptions here, but I'll walk you through it.

If the connection between `table_a` and `table_b` is tenuous, and there are possible duplicate `(name,rack)` pairs, you might want to do the updates one at a time.

First, take the contents of your staging table and put them into a temp table. We're going to be deleting rows from the temp table during this process, so you probably don't want to do this directly with `table_a`. Once you have that, we're going to loop through the records with a `WHILE` loops, and update `table_b` one record at a time.

```
DECLARE @A_ID INT

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #table_a)
BEGIN

    --Get one ID value at a time
    SELECT TOP 1 @A_ID = id 
    FROM #table_a

    --the CTE gets the first record from table_b that needs an [object] value set
    ;WITH Top1B AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 b.id, objectId = p.id
        FROM #table_b b
        INNER JOIN #table_a a ON a.[name] = b.[name] AND a.rack = b.rack
        INNER JOIN #table_param p ON p.nameObject = a.object
        WHERE a.id = @A_ID
            AND b.object IS NULL
    )
    UPDATE b
    SET b.[object] = tb.objectId
    FROM Top1B tb
    INNER JOIN #table_b b ON b.id = tb.id

    --remove the record from the staging table
    DELETE #table_a
    WHERE id = @A_ID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `table_b.ID` attribute is an `IDENTITY`, and are automatically generated, you need to `JOIN` `table_a` to `table_parameterization` using the object. You'll get the values to insert into `B` using something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.Name,
    a.rack,
    p.ID
FROM table_a_staging a
    INNER JOIN table_parametrization p ON
        a.object = p.nameObject
```

Comment: I think the question is too unclear to even asses this answer.